# What's the diff of [for 'elem' in myList] to [for 'i' in range(x, y)], referencing to list element

Tags: python, list, for-loop

I looked at the selection-sort algorithm using python (3.6.2).

I recognized that all of the solutions/examples would use explicit numbers to refer at an index in the list.

Example:

```py
def selection_sort(content):
    content_length = len(content)
    for position in range(content_length):
        for next_pos in range(position+1, content_length):
            if content[next_pos] < content[position]:
                content[next_pos], content[position] = content[position], content[next_pos]
```

While I tried it like this:

```py
def selection_sort(content):
    for position in content:
        for next_pos in (content):
            if next_pos < position:
                position, next_pos = next_position, position
```

And some variations with `content[next_pos]` and `content[position]`.

My solution would just do nothing. Not even an error... The list gets returned in the same order as inserted into the function.

Why? :-)
What is the difference between `elem` like in `for elem in my_list:` and `content[i]`.

Or am I missing something in this line?
`position, next_pos = next_position, position`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the second snippet actually you are exchanging the values of two variables having same value as the array content actual array remains untouched.

```
position, next_pos = next_position, position
```

This swaps  just values of two valuables having values of array elements.

But this change the content of the array by accessing it's elements by index.

```
content[next_pos], content[position] = content[position], content[next_pos]
```

Happy Coding:)